# outline mode: Fold everything when loading file (specifically LaTeX mode)

Tags: latex, auctex, code-folding, outline-mode

I am using outline minor mode for LaTeX mode and would like emacs to automatically hide all section environments when opening a `.tex` file. How could I do that?

Comment: Does that mean you are using the built-in `tex-mode.el` library, or does that mean you are using the separate library that does not ship with Emacs called `AUCTeX`?

Comment: I am using AUCTeX.

Answer (score 1):

The specific function you are looking for is
`outline-hide-sublevels`.  Its docstring (`C-h f
outline-hide-sublevels`) reads:

> `(outline-hide-sublevels LEVELS)`
>
> Hide everything but the top LEVELS levels of headers, in whole buffer.
>   This also unhides the top heading-less body, if any.
>
> Interactively, the prefix argument supplies the value of LEVELS.
>   When invoked without a prefix argument, LEVELS defaults to the level
>   of the current heading, or to 1 if the current line is not a heading.

Programmatically, `(outline-hide-sublevels 1)` will fold up
everything to the top level (which is what you want).  You can
make a little function to do that:

```
(defun my-latex-hook ()
  (outline-hide-sublevels 1))
```

And add it to your `LaTeX` mode hook:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-latex-hook)
```

See the manual node
on
[outline visibility commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Visibility.html#Outline-Visibility) for
more information.

Comment: thanks, but when I save the document everything unfolds again. That also happens when I manually fold blocks though.

Comment: @lotolmencre : please try it after starting up without your init file (emacs -Q). That doesn’t sound like standard behavior, so it’s likely something in your init file.